# Can I create electric current with constant intensity by a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

If I just switch the direction of a magnetic field (to opposite side) that passes through a coil, do I create electric current on my coil? Would this induced current have constant intensity? Would it only change its direction along the time?
The graphic of this phenomen would be a little strange, its function wouldn't be continuous. So I wonder if it is possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you switch the direction of the magnetic field through a coil, that changes the flux. Whether it's a sinusoidal variation, or something else, doesn't matter - the rate of change of flux determines the induced e.m.f.. And knowing the EMF and the resistance of the coil will allow you to calculate the current.

Of course, the current that is induced will itself affect the flux (Lenz's Law, Faraday's Law, ...).

Not sure what you mean with your last sentence ("alternate switching directions but not intensities") - would you care to elaborate?

Comment: tell me if it's okay to understand.
I was asking that considering a change of 180º on the magnetic field direction. I think the flux wouldn't change, so it wouldn't create current. But my teacher said it would be possible.

Comment: If you rotate the field by 180 degrees you change the flux. By 2 times it's initial value in fact. Btw. it's not possible to do that change in zero time. Everything in physics always takes some amount of time.